# Chrome on Ubuntu freezes in maximised mode

Tags: google-chrome

When I maximise the window in Chrome in Ubuntu, the browser stays active although the UI does not update. I have installed GIMP recently and nothing else major since this has happened, and restarting does not solve the issue.

Here is a video of the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS3nLWzJdrQ

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Having too little RAM can lead to things being really, really, slow and laggy. Chrome _does_ have a history of being a huge resource hogger. If you don't have much, try using [Chromium (with WideVine Support)](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta), or [Firefox](http://firefox.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, it will solve your problem:
[Screen freezes when going full-screen mode - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912138/screen-freezes-when-going-full-screen-mode-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

> Create a file named `20-modesetting.conf` under the
> `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory, with the following content:
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
>    Driver      "modesetting"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> Some people suggest removing the Intel graphics driver entirely
> (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152#c73):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
> ```
>
> This will essentially force Ubuntu to use the modesetting driver.
>
> I think it is a more elegant solution to leave the Intel graphics
> driver as is and just override it with a simple configuration file.
>
> For the moment, the Intel graphics driver is responsible for many
> problems, such as freezing when in full screen mode and flickering in
> Google Chrome.

By the way, does the freeze always happen or only when you open a tab which uses a lot of resources, like a tab playing a video, etc?

Comment: Works! Although you should probably link the answer in future instead of a weird youtube video: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912138/screen-freezes-when-going-full-screen-mode-ubuntu-16-04-lts